# Java groups exception JGRP000002 using hotspot jdk6

Tags: maven-2, jvm-hotspot, jgroups

I am migrating my application from jrockit jdk6 to hotspot jdk6. While building my application using maven, one of my integration test makes the build to hang with below error message:

```
jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProvider,ERROR,Failed to create JGroups Channel, replication will not function. JGroups properties:
${jgroups.cache.config}
java.lang.Exception: JGRP000002: unable to load protocol $ (either with relative - $ - or absolute - org.jgroups.protocols.$ - class name)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createLayer(Configurator.java:430)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createProtocols(Configurator.java:397)
```

Please throw some light!

Comment: JGroups is loading it's protocol stack definitions from a file. In JGroups 3.4.4.Final line 430 would indicate it has failed to find and/or load one of the classes defined in the protocol stack configuration. Which version of JGroups are you using?

Comment: I would guess the protocol stack definition that you are using to configure your stack has '$' characters in it instead of real protocols. Does your test code do some sort of String replacement perhaps that isn't being carried out. How do you specify and configure the protocol stack for your integration tests?

Comment: Why are you migrating to an end-of-life and unsupported JDK?